# YouTube Data API - How to specify the channel you're uploading to?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am creating an application which will be deployed on various sites and will upload videos from each site to YouTube periodically. I have already got videos uploading but ideally each site would have its own channel.

I had a search to see if anyone has encountered this issue (Don't reinvent the wheel, right?) but the only thing that I found was a couple of threads referencing the onBehalfOfContentOwner parameter [detailed in the api here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert).

This isn't relevant to me as I'm not a content partner; at least I don't think I am. The Google API help documents then sent me here, so here I am.

I have created a YouTube brand account with, for the moment, two channels. Obviously, each one has their own channel id. So far I have tried the following:

- Specifying the ChannelId when creating a Video Snippet, I couldn't see anywhere else to set it or an appropriate object to use. I tried with two different channel ids using the same OAuth credentials.
- Creating two separate api projects with two unique OAuth credentials and then loading these credentials at runtime. I was only using one set of credentials throughout the lifetime of the app and then changed to the second credential set once I had tested that the upload was still working. The first credential set that I used prompted me to login and
  subsequently select an account. The second set didn't prompt me at
  all but the video was uploaded on the same account that I had
  selected previously. I was logged out of YouTube and my browser was
  closed in both instances; the browser does not store any details once it is closed.

I guess really my question is this. What is the best practice for specifying which channel you want to upload to? The application I'm using will be running automatically at set times, so I cannot have user interaction during the upload process. (Selecting an account during initial setup would be fine though!)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I found that the API automatically uses an access token on the local machine if one is present in ***C:\Users{USERNAME}\AppData\Roaming\Google.Apis.Auth*** ; even if I am using a different OAuth credential in my application. Deleting the access token file will cause a login prompt to appear the next time you use the api from this machine.

For my application, this will be acceptable as when I deploy there is only the need for a one-time login and gain the access token which will then refresh every hour. It will also mean that I can choose which account/channel I am uploading to for each of our sites. Whilst I acknowledge the answer given by MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0, I do not believe that this is applicable here given that I am not a content partner as previously mentioned.

If someone can tell me how to do this through code instead of deleting the access token, that would of course be a preferred solution. (Or let me know that I am a content partner so I can try the onBehalf parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that removing the OAuth token on the PC that my application is running on allows me to reselect the account/channel that I'm uploading to.

It appears that the authorised channel is determined using this token and once present it will automatically refresh every hour. Seeing as one PC will only ever upload to one channel for a given site, I think it is acceptable that I will have to go through a one time setup for each site to gain a token.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to specify the channel you need to upload the video, i think you may need [this parameter](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#parameters) in your code:

> `onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel`- This parameter can only be used in a
>   properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). This parameter can only be used in a
>   properly [authorized request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication). **Note**: This parameter is intended
>   exclusively for YouTube content partners.
>
> The **onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel** parameter specifies the YouTube
>   channel ID of the channel to which a video is being added. This
>   parameter is required when a request specifies a value for the
>   **onBehalfOfContentOwner** parameter, and it can only be used in conjunction with that parameter. In addition, the request must be
>   authorized using a CMS account that is linked to the content owner
>   that the **onBehalfOfContentOwner** parameter specifies. Finally, the
>   channel that the **onBehalfOfContentOwnerChannel** parameter value
>   specifies must be linked to the content owner that the
>   **onBehalfOfContentOwner** parameter specifies.
>
> This parameter is intended for YouTube content partners that own and
>   manage many different YouTube channels. It allows content owners to
>   authenticate once and perform actions on behalf of the channel
>   specified in the parameter value, without having to provide
>   authentication credentials for each separate channel.

Comment: Cheers for the response. I haven't tried the parameter that you recommended (Which I had already found from the API documentation), as I found that removing the OAuth token on the PC that my application is running on allows me to reselect the account/channel that I'm uploading to.

It appears that the authorised channel is determined using this token and once present it will automatically refresh every hour. Seeing as one PC will only ever upload to one channel for a given site, I think it is acceptable that I will have to go through a one time setup for each site to gain a token.